# Regarding an equation in an iteration method

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, steady-state

I am going through a paper on an iterative method related to discrete optimal regulator,
*G. Hewer, "An iterative technique for the computation of the steady state gains for the discrete optimal regulator," in IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control*,
where Theorem 1 in the paper is given below

Theorem 1: Let $V_k,k=0,1,2..$ be the solution of the equation
$$
V_k=\Phi_k'V_k\Phi_k+L_k'RL_k+C'C
$$
where
$$
L_k=(D'V_{k-1}D+R)^{-1}D'V_{k-1}\Phi,\ \ for\  k=1,2,...\\
\Phi_k=\Phi-DL_k,\ \ k=0,1,2,...
$$
and $L_0$ is chosen such that $\Phi_0$ is a stability matrix. Then
$$
K\le V_{k+1} \le V_k...,\ k=0,1,...
$$
and $\lim_{k\to \infty}V_k=K.\ \square$

All the above variables are matrices of appropriate dimension.

In the proof of the theorem, at the very beginning there is an identity
$$
\Phi_0'V_0\Phi_0+L_0'RL_0=\Phi_1'V_0\Phi_1+L_1'RL_1+(L_1-L_0)'(D'V_0D+R)(L_1-L_0)\ \ \ \ \ (7)
$$
I could not arrive at (7) exactly.
My attempt is as follows:
From $\Phi_k=\Phi-DL_k$, construct
$$
\Phi_0=\Phi-DL_0\\
\Phi_1=\Phi-DL_1\\
\Phi_0-\Phi_1=D(L_1-L_0)\\
(\Phi_0-\Phi_1)'V_0(\Phi_0-\Phi_1)=(L_1-L_0)'D'V_0D(L_1-L_0)
$$
Adding $(L_1-L_0)'R(L_1-L_0)$ on both sides
$$
\begin{align}
(\Phi_0-\Phi_1)'V_0(\Phi_0-\Phi_1)+(L_1-L_0)'R(L_1-L_0)&=(L_1-L_0)'D'V_0D(L_1-L_0)+(L_1-L_0)'R(L_1-L_0)\\
&=(L_1-L_0)'(D'V_0D+R)(L_1-L_0)\end{align}
 $$
which is not exactly (7). I could not see where the mistake is and any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In the paper, the author mentions the similarity of this equation with one obtained by Wonham. Did you check this paper? Also, what you did is correct but you have not used the definition for $L_1$ and $V_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that I have not used the definitions for $L_1$ and $V_0$. I will look into the paper by Wonham again.

Comment: You may look at the continuous-time case in the Kleinman's thesis which can be found there: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/31024/25736670-MIT.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y The discrete-time is certainly analogous.